# Making a for X in Y loop return whatever is returned by the statements it contains

Tags: ruby, loops, return, for-loop

The following statement...

```
content_tag(:li, concept.title)
```

...returns something like:

```
<li>"My big idea"</li>
```

The following method definition, when called, returns the same:

```
def list_of_concepts(part)
 content_tag(:li, concept.title)
end
```

As does...

```
def list_of_concepts(part)
 content_tag(:li, part.concepts.first.title)
end
```

But the following...

```
def list_of_concepts(part)
  for concept in part.concepts
    content_tag(:li, concept.title)
  end
end
```

...just gives me a bunch of pound signs ("`#`") in my view, like it's returning true or false or a count rather than whatever `content_tag` returns. How can I make it return what `content_tag` returns?

Thanks again,

Steven.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the for loop doesn't return your data, try this:

```
def list_of_concepts(part)
  part.concepts.map { |c| content_tag(:li, c.title) }.join
end
```